# How do I fix the coding error: " Use of Unresolved Identifier SafariVC". The error is next to "SafariVC.delegate = self"

Tags: swift, error-handling

I'm setting up `SFSafariViewController` in my DetailVC.  Where do I need to set up coding to resolved the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier SafariVC

The error shows next to: `safariVC.delegate = self`.

```
import SafariServices
import UIKit

class StateDetailViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func watchButtonTapped(_ sender: SAButton) {
      if let url = URL(string: self.state!.url) {
        UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        present(safariVC, animated: true)
      }
      safariVC.delegate = self
  }
  @IBOutlet weak var stateTitleTextLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stateDetailTextTitleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var stateDescriptionTextView: UITextView!

  var state: State?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    title = "Reciprocal Details"

    stateTitleTextLabel.text = state?.title
    stateDetailTextTitleLabel.text = state?.detailText
    stateDescriptionTextView.text = state?.description

    func safariViewControllerDidFinish(_ controller: SFSafariViewController) {
      controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Fix your indenting and the issue is obvious (assuming you are familiar with variable scope).

Comment: I will google it as I do not know, as I am still a newbie to swift and my first time coding.  Sorry!

Comment: Can you tell me the obvious please.  I am trying to learn the right way!  Thanks

Comment: A variable is only available inside the curly braces it was declared in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
  if let url = URL(string: self.state!.url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    present(safariVC, animated: true)
  }
  safariVC.delegate = self
```

To

```
  if let url = URL(string: self.state!.url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    safariVC.delegate = self
    present(safariVC, animated: true)
  }
```